# Django Social Auth - User is Created, Profile is Created, But User Is Not Logged In

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-socialauth

So as the title goes, I am able to be use Facebook to create a new user and create a new profile. However, I am not being logged in. I am always redirected to /login/ (with some characters at the end). With this code, what could I be missing?

my settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = lambda u: slugify(u)
SOCIAL_AUTH_UUID_LENGTH = 10
SOCIAL_AUTH_EXTRA_DATA = False
SOCIAL_AUTH_EXPIRATION = 'expires'
SOCIAL_AUTH_INACTIVE_USER_URL = '/inactive/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = DEBUG
SOCIAL_AUTH_CHANGE_SIGNAL_ONLY = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_BY_MAIL = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_associate_complete'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_backends',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_login_redirect',
)
```

my models.py

```
signals.post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
pre_update.connect(facebook_extra_values, sender=FacebookBackend)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    photo = ImageField(upload_to="profile_pictures")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('profiles_profile_detail', (), {'username':self.user.username})

    get_absolute_url = models.permalink(get_absolute_url)
```

my receivers.py

```
def facebook_extra_values(sender, instance, response, details, **kwargs):
    """
    post_save signal from User model; check bzuser.models
    for the connection

    """
    from .models import UserProfile
    UserProfile(user=instance).save()
    return True
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/$', custom_login),
    url(r'^logout/$', custom_logout),
    url(r'^social_login/$', SocialLoginView.as_view(), name="social_login"),
    (r'', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^register$', 'registration.views.register', {
        'form_class': RegistrationFormUniqueEmail,
        'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend'
    }, name='registration_register'),
    (r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),
    url(r'^profile', ProfileView.as_view(), name="profile_private"),
)
```

and my views.py

```
class ProfileView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'

class SocialLoginView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SocialLoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = _('Log In With Facebook or Twitter')
        return context

    template_name = 'social.html'

def custom_login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profiles_profile_detail',
            kwargs={"username":request.user.username}))
    else:
        return login(request)

def custom_logout(request):
    return logout_then_login(request)
```

and my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="title">
            <img class="titleIcon" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/icons/dark/preview.png" />
            <h6>Social Login</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="body textC">
            <a class="wButton bluewB m10"
                href="{% url socialauth_begin 'facebook' %}{% if request.GET.next %}?next={{ request.GET.next }}{% endif %}">
                <span>Log In With Facebook</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Added AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS constant

the urls.py from an app

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # project specific urls
    url(r'', include('base.urls')),
    url(r'', include('bzuser.urls')),

    # 3rd party URLS
    ('^nexus/', include(nexus.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
)
```

**EDIT:** Added social auth inclusion URLS

Comment: Which is the value for `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`? Also, ditch the `pre_update` signal on `FacebookBackend` and use the [pipeline](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html) instead

Comment: see the edit for the value of AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS. Thanks for the tip. I will apply it :D

Comment: Where's the inclusion of `social_auth` urls?

Comment: added urls. they are from an app's urls

Comment: Checking your code that creates the profile, are you sure that query is safe? What happens on collisions?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved it finally.
You should use the authentication [pipeline](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html)! and ensure to associate by email. so that your have something like

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.associate.associate_by_email',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session',
    'people.pipeline.redirect_to_get_phonenumber_form',
    'people.pipeline.phonenumber',
    'people.pipeline.save_new_persons_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
)
```